# emscripten - libavcodec - time_t unresolved using declaration

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

using `libavcodec` headers, `emscripten` is failing to compile to `WASM`.
It is indicating issue in the C++17 `chrono` date library.

[image]

Any pointers would be great here.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace!

Comment: Posting an error message without the code is discouraged as well. Update your question after reading this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Since time_t is a common type, there is something missing from your question to help answer it.